# vertical alignment of the equation label in amsmath

Tags: equations, labels

I have an equation which is almost as long as the linewidth of my document. Hence, the equation number is moved into the next line. Normally this is totally fine for me. However, I have one equation which includes an underbrace and therefore, there is quite lot of space within the equation. Look at the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{align}
    aaa & = -\underbrace{bbbbbbbb\frac{cccccc}{dddddd\frac{den}{DE}}}_{=\frac{x}{y}} + zzzzz-zzzzzzzz+zzzz \label{eq:induced_amplitude_change}
    \end{align}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

There would be enough space to move the label a little bit higher. Since I need to get rid of one or two lines in my whole document, this would help me a lot. Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: `amsmath` tries its best but also provides `\raisetag{length}` to adjust the vertical position of a tag.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to split the equation over two lines.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{equation}
        aaa  = -\underbrace{bbbbbbbb\frac{cccccc}{dddddd\frac{den}{DE}}}_{=\frac{x}{y}} + zzzzz-zzzzzzzz+zzzz \label{eq:induced_amplitude_change}  
    \end{equation}
    \lipsum[1]
\begin{gather}\raisetag{5ex}
aaa  = -\underbrace{bbbbbbbb\frac{cccccc}{dddddd\frac{den}{DE}}}_{=\frac{x}{y}} + zzzzz-zzzzzzzz+zzzz \label{eq:induced_amplitude_change2}  
\end{gather}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{multline}
aaa  = -\underbrace{bbbbbbbb\frac{cccccc}{dddddd\frac{den}{DE}}}_{=x\mathrel/ y} \\
+ zzzzz-zzzzzzzz+zzzz \label{eq:induced_amplitude_change3}  
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: as I said, I rather have too many lines, that's why I try to squeeze everything rather than extend it. `\raisetag{}` actually did its job.

Comment: It doesn't work in OP's align environment, either. but thanks for pointing out that it works in gather.  But either one uses a single equation, in which case gather causes spacing issues, or one has multiple equations, in which case the problem doesn't arise.

Comment: It doesn't for me.... hmmmm.

Comment: OK, now I'm puzzled. If I take the original question and simply add `\raisetag{2ex}` it works. I've got `amsmath 2016/03/10 v2.15b` and `IEEEtran 2015/08/26 V1.8b`.

Comment: Same IEEEtran, but amsmath 2016/11/05 v2.16a

Comment: And doesn't work for me in gather, either.

Comment: I can't update the installation on my work computer but copying the newest version in the local folder (and renaming it just to be sure) still works for me... And it works also if I copy-paste your code and change the second `equation` into `gather`.

Comment: Hmmm....  I have two identical installations on different computers.  One with issues, and one without.  Since this appears to be an issue with my installation, I'll edit my answer.